# Remote Desktop Settings Missing

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm trying to setup remote connection to my Windows 10 machine. During the setup I noticed that my installation is missing some settings all the tutorials have. Can anyone tell me why I'm stupid and what I should do? Below you can find a screenshot of what I'm talking about. The first image is how it should be. The second picture is a screenshot on my machine.

[image: How it should look like]

[image: How it actually looks like]

Edit: After popular request, my windows version:
[image]

Comment: What's the Windows version are you using? If do not know, can you open **run** dialog by holding the `WIN + R` key together and type `winver`, then post the screen that appears?

Comment: Thanks for the shortcut, I had to Google it otherwise :-)

Comment: I have not tried the **remote assistance** feature but however, that is a handy tool too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I couldn't really see the version but it seems you're on a **HOME** edition.

As per Microsoft's Official site comparison says that **Windows 10 Home** has no RDP feature listed.

[image]

You might want to compare the features as to per your needs, then look to upgrade for a suitable version.

Source: **[Compare Windows 10 Editions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/Compare)**

Answer (score 5):

You are using the Windows 10 **Home** edition. Home editions of Windows do not contain the built-in RDP feature.

Remote Desktop (RDP) has always been a built-in feature of the Pro and higher versions, leaving Home without RDP. There are other 3rd party solutions though which can be used with the Home version, including VNC.

Or you could upgrade to the Windows 10 **Pro** version.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply type MSRA in RUN, and create new remote invite and send it with password to the person who you want to access your system,