# Setting up RDP on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-connection

I am trying to set up a remote connection from the laptop which I bring with me to work and my Desktop I have at my home. I tried setting up an RDP connection but the remote system properties doesn't have the same options as what was done in the youtube tutorial I was using.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geD6b_-4M-E

[Screenshot of what my system properties looks like vs the one in the tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8l35.png)

Comment: What edition of Windows are you running?

Comment: As I know, the windows home version don't have built-in Remote Desktop. And this could be duplicated with https://superuser.com/questions/1019203/remote-desktop-settings-missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote Desktop Settings Missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1019203/remote-desktop-settings-missing)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the Windows version, it is only possible to make connection via RDP to professional and enterprise versions. Or you can use other methods such as installing RDP functions by hand.  [Tutorial - RDP Wrapper in Windows 10 home](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-rdpwrapper-win10-home)

Comment: Please include the essential elements of linked content so your answer remains useful after the links break.