# Why's remote desktop missing?

Tags: remote-desktop

I live Toronto. I have family in China and New York. We must remotely access each's desktop. All have Windows 10.

TeamViewer [falsely blocked us for commercial use](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Why-do-I-see-Commercial-use-suspected-Commercial-use-detected/ta-p/5265#toc-hId--1787793577). We requested unblock, but no answer yet. I'm having issues with AnyDesk and will post later.

Anyhow please see screen shot beneath from [0.51](https://youtu.be/gsP46ltENRY?t=51).

[image]

Comment: RDP is an enterprise technology. It requires port forwarding and potentially exposing your computers to attacks from the internet. Stick with the other applications you mentioned. Leave RDP for systems admins.

Comment: Upgrade your Windows 10 Home installation to Windows 10 Professional or use a third-party Remote Desktop client of your choice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote Desktop Settings Missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1019203/remote-desktop-settings-missing)

Comment: @Appleoddity i can't use free versions of Team Viewer or Any Desk as i explained.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Windows Home edition doesn't support the remote desktop feature. It's available only in the Pro and Enterprise edition.

How to check if your system supports remote desktop:

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key + <kbd>I</kbd> to open the Settings app, click on
   **System** and choose the "**Remote Desktop**" page.
2. On the right pane, you can see if the remote desktop settings are available. If
   it's not available, you can click the suggested link on that page to
   upgrade your Windows 10 edition.